# Dismiss Keyboard when user touches outside TextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

I am using this method but keyboard isn't hiding.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
   [_myTextView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

How can I dismiss the keyboard on simply touching outside the keyboard. Would be great if the solution is for both objective c and swift. Thanks

I have a query in objective C for textView inside scrollView. Please resolve. I've searched but have found no discrete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
     [self.yourScrollviewName endEditing:YES];
}
```

or use like

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (![[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]]) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self.yourScrollviewName endEditing:YES];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

the above code not work try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   UITapGestureRecognizer  *resignView = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTapforResign:)];
    resignView.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: resignView];
}
```

Dismiss what ever is currently editing:

```
- (void) handleSingleTapforResign:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [self.yourScrollviewName endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: I replaced self.view with self.myTextView (textView outlet). Tried it. Nothing happens. Keyboard stays as it was.

Comment: in your view has added in scrollview or normal view

Comment: Inside scroll view

Comment: @Sam- sorry for delay,Network is down, check the updated answer

Comment: Worked! Thanks man!

Comment: @Sam-welcome bro, accept the answer is useful